# apply() and forceAndCall() ignoring get() from parent.frame()

Tags: r, apply

I don't understand why this code is failing on the last printed line:

```
f <- function(x) get('v', envir = parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE)

run <- function() {

  v <- 'test variable'

  print(f())
  print((function() f())())
  print(apply(X = data.frame(1:2), MARGIN = 1, f))
}
run()
```

with:

```
 Error in get("v", envir = parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE) : 
  object 'v' not found
```

The first print statement shows that `v` is found in `parent.frame(1)`. The second print statement shows that `v` is found in `parent.frame(2)` due to `inherits = TRUE`. The last one is the enigma.

Seems that `apply` is ignoring the `get(envir = parent.frame())`. I traced this back to function `forceAndCall()` within `apply()`. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

In real application, `v` is only defined in the calling environment of the function `f` (i.e. in `parent.frame()` or above), but never in `parent.env()`.

Comment: Interesting. I added an function wrapping `f`, after the first `print` line, `g <- function() { f() };   print(g())`, which performed as expected and without error. So the `inherits` argument works as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue here are the calling environments and the way `get(inherits=TRUE)` handles them. For starters, I suggest one reads Hadley's [Function environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs).

More specifically, one has to understand function's enclosing and calling environments to understand what is going on.

`v` is defined in the function `f` calling environment, which is -- looking from the function's execution environment -- `parent.frame(1L)` in the first print statement, and `parent.frame(2L)` in the last two print statements.

I thought that if I supply `envir=parent.frame(1L)` with `inherits=TRUE`, the `get` function would traverse the `parent.frame()` hierarchy and eventually find `v` in one of the parent *calling* environments. It does not. In reality it starts from the `envir` environment one supplies and looks in the parent *enclosing* environments for `v`. For the second print statement, the enclosing parent environment of `parent.frame(1L)` is exactly where `v` is defined, but in the last print statement, the enclosing parent environment of `parent.frame(1L)` is the `base` namespace where `apply` is defined. Enclosing parent environment on top of that is the global environment. So `v` is not found.

What we really need is a `get` function that doesn't search in the parent enclosing environments hierarchy for `v`, but in parent calling environments hierarchy. And that is exactly what `dynget()` does.

> dynGet() is somewhat experimental and to be used inside another
>   function. It looks for an object in the callers, i.e., the
>   sys.frame()s of the function. Use with caution

This function will traverse the parent calling environments `sys.parents()` with `sys.frame()` and look for `v` in each of them. So `f <- function(x) dynGet('v', inherits = TRUE)` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not relay a solution but it avoids the error.
The manual of `parent.frame` say: convenient shorthand for `sys.frame(sys.parent(n))`. Using `sys.frame(sys.parent(n))` results in the same error. But when I ask for `sys.parents()` and take the one before the last the error disappears or simply use `dynGet` as found out by @DavorJosipovic.

```
#f <- function(x) get('v', envir = sys.frame(max(0, sys.parents()[length(sys.parents())-1])), inherits = TRUE)
f <- function(x) dynGet('v', inherits = TRUE)
run <- function() {
  v <- 'test variable'
  print(f())
  print((function() f())())
  print(apply(X = data.frame(1:2), MARGIN = 1, f))
}
run()
#[1] "test variable"
#[1] "test variable"
#[1] "test variable" "test variable"
```

Comment: Its quite hackish but it works @GKi :D. In the real application I solved it with argument passing. to `f`. But you have a point. `sys.parents()` returns the correct indices. The real solution -- as far as I understand it up till now -- would involve checking for `v` in each `sys.frame()` environment for each of `sys.parents()`. Seems that `get` with `inherits = TRUE` checks the parent *environments* of `parent.frame()`, leading it to an other inheritance tree which is not the call stack. So the more I think of it, the more I think it is an unfortunate feature and not really a bug :/.

Comment: And now that I realized the above: seems `dynGet('v', inherits = TRUE)` does exactly that. *dynGet() is somewhat experimental and to be used inside another function. It looks for an object in the callers, i.e., the sys.frame()s of the function. Use with caution.* Well GKi, since I can't answer my own question yet: you have the honor :D.

Comment: @DavorJosipovic Oh yes! Simply `f <- function(x) dynGet('v', inherits = TRUE)` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

As @Davor said, invoking `apply` adds another layer of parent.frame() which leads to a new environment path, here is one way to search in two different environments.

```
f <- function(x) {
  cat('f Env.')
  print(environment())
  #browser()
  if(is.null(get0('v', parent.frame()))) {
    get('v', envir = parent.frame(2), inherits = TRUE)} else {
      get('v', envir = parent.frame(1), inherits = TRUE)}
}

run <- function() {
  cat('run Env.')
  print(environment())
  v <- 'test variable'
  print(f())
  print((function() f())())
  print(apply(X = data.frame(1:2), MARGIN = 1, f))

}
run()
```

If we un-comment `browser()` in `f`, comment the 1st and 2nd `print` in `run` and rerun the code we can see that `parent.frame()` and `parent.frame(2)` have different `parent.env`

[image]

Comment: I think I have it. `parent.frame()` resolves to `<environment: 0x00000000211164a8>` under `<environment: namespace:base>` when called from within `apply`. Above that is the global environment, so it will never find `v`. `parent.frame(2)` correctly finds the environment where `v` is defined. So its like `apply` is changing the calling stack.

Comment: Yes, the old `run()` was not ideally formulated. I think now it is much better. In any case, `parent.frame(2)` is not the real solution. `get('v', envir = parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE)` should work in any case, but due to my previous comment, it doesn't. I am not sure how to understand this: bug or feature? The docs say *Strictly, sys.parent and parent.frame refer to the context of the parent interpreted function. So internal functions (which may or may not set contexts and so may or may not appear on the call stack) may not be counted, and S3 methods can also do surprising things.* Yey...

Comment: "*For `n=2` only `print(apply(X = data.frame(1:2), MARGIN = 1, f))` works.*" `print((function() f())())` should also work due to the extra call. I understand the stack increase, but in this example, something else is going on: `print(apply(X = data.frame(1:2), MARGIN = 1, f))` changes the call hierarchy, while `print((function() f())())` maintains it. That is why `print((function() f())())` also works with `n = 1` and `inheritance = TRUE`. This changing call hierarchy that `apply` introduces is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this fully answers the question, and I don't fully understand how the namespaces/environments are resolved. But consider this extension to your code, where I've defined my own "apply" functions. One defined in the calling `run` function, one defined outside:

```
X <- data.frame(1:2)

my_apply1 <- function(X, FUN) {
    for (i in seq_along(X)) {
      print(FUN(X[[i]]))
    }
}
run <- function() {
  f <- function(x) get('v', envir = parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE)

  v <- 'test variable'

  print(f())
  g <- function() { f() };   print(g())

  my_apply2 <- function(X, FUN) {
    for (i in seq_along(X)) {
      print(FUN(X[[i]]))
    }
  }

  my_apply2(X, f)
  my_apply1(X, f)


  #print(my_apply(matrix(1:6, ncol=2), MARGIN = 1, f))
}
run()
```

> ```
> [1] "test variable"
> [1] "test variable"
> [1] "test variable"
> Error in get("v", envir = parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE) :
>     object 'v' not found
> ```

This indicates to me, that the environment inheritance does not follow the same path as the nesting functions, in the sense that the parsing occours as

```
run() => f() => base::apply() => f() => where is v?
```

whereas finding the variable `v` follows back where the functions are defined

```
where is v? => f() => base::apply => base => v?
```

Comment: So, If I follow you correctly, this means that `inherits = TRUE` is confusing since it doesn't apply to environment defined in `envir` but always applies to `parent.env()` and above.

Comment: You could be onto something there, that it's actually following back the enclosing environments of `apply`, not `f` (which is what I came to in my answer), but your comment formulates it much better.

Comment: I just updated the question. `inherits = TRUE` follows nicely the `envir` argument. So the problem is elsewhere. cf. Suliman's answer.