# r: object not found when using fourier within a formula within a function

Tags: r, formula, forecasting, lm

(using the `forecast` package in `r`). if I write:

```
tslmf <- function(y, h, myK,...) {
  fourier(y, myK)
}
```

I can call it with `tslmf(taylor, h=1, c(1,1))` and everything works.
but if I write:

```
tslmf <- function(y, h, myK,...) {
  fit <- tslm(y ~ trend + fourier(y, K=myK))
}
```

and call it exactly the same, I get:
`object 'myK' not found`

AND if I do:

```
tslmf <- function(y, h, myK,...) {
  z <- fourier(y, myK)
  fit <- tslm(y ~ trend + z)
}
```

it does work!

why is that?

Comment: It works fine for me. Mac 10.6.8

Comment: @drJones - pretty sure it doesn't :( R version 3.6.1 os darwin15.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fourier` called inside `tslm` is looking for `myK` in the environments `forcast`, `base` and `global` and there it does not find them. The *enclosing environment* of `tslm` is NOT the environment of your function, where you have `myK`.

See [Function environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs), [apply() and forceAndCall() ignoring get() from parent.frame()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57672803/10488504) or [Accessing variables passed to, or defined in, parent R function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58376489/10488504).

Comment: Thanks! will read and get educated... meanwhile, is my workaround legit? `z <- fourier(y, myK); fit <- tslm(y ~ trend + z)`

Comment: @ihadanny When it works it will be OK. Maybe you write a new question with this topic, as I can not really decide on this.